# UIwebview Touch and readaloud (speak) using TTS AVSpeechSynthesizer

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

I have an `UIWebView` in my iPhone app.

When user touch on `UIWebView` the touched element should be readaloud Back. Like speak button used from UIMenuController.

With following code I can get text from paragraph. In order to following code to work, I need to use Long press to make selection on `UIWebView`. I just want to touch and get text.

```
NSLog(@"Text : %@\n\n",[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"(window.getSelection()).anchorNode.textContent"]);
```

Is there any why I can get text and also highlight pragraph (selected element).

Many thank in advance.

Comment: Does any one have answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer!!

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.ontouchstart  = function (e) {e.target.style.background='#ff3355';};"];

Comment: -(void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
        NSString *text =[_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.ontouchstart  = function (e) {e.target.style.background='#ff00ff';                     var text = e.target.textContent;                     alert (text);                     Return text;                     };"];
}Why I always get TEXT return empty;